# closedXML insert subcollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, closedxml

I'm getting my collection from database

```
var exclCompany = companies.Select(u => new ExcelCompaniesViewModel
{
    Id = u.Id,
    IsEditedFirstTime = u.IsEditedFirstTime ? "Да" : "Нет",
    IsLoggedFirstTime = u.IsLoggedFirstTime ? "Да" : "Нет",
    Title = u.Title,
    Description = u.Description,
    Members = u.RmCompanyMembers.Select(p => new CompanyMemberViewModel
    {
        MemberDateLogin = "12/10/12",
        MemberName = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", p.LastName, p.FirstName, p.MiddleName),
        TelephoneMemers = p.Phone
    }).ToArray()

});
```

and insert into worksheet.

```
workSheet.Cell(2, 1).InsertData(exclCompany);
```

But in result file, cells with members displayed as:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator
```

How to insert collections with subcollections?

Comment: Do You must use `.ToArray()` at the end of the select? Can You `.ToList()` for example?

Comment: System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator is the type of exclCompany. You have to call .ToArray() or .ToList() to actually execute the LINQ query and retrieve the data.

Comment: I believe it's called. At the end of the `u.RmCompanyMembers.Select(...).ToArray()`

Answer (score 0):

If You have access to modify the code to use `.ToList()`, and not `.ToArray()`, than You can use this:

Change the type of Members to something that implements the `IList` interface, and override the `ToString()` method. This way, You will have Your way to visualize an array. For example:

```
public class MembersCollection: IList<CompanyMemberViewModel>
...
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(", ", this);
    }
}
```

And of course don't forget to implement the `ToString()` of CompanyMemberViewModel.